# Issue trying to escape a string in javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap Tab plugin for `CKEditor`, and it works well. But, when i use a single quote on content (doesn't matter if the string is "'", or " or '), it broke up.

I guess is just a escape issue. I tried with `escape()` and `encodeURI()`, but fails.

> Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list;
>   Source:
>   x)PRE3015 Pino 1/2'' 15mm Ponta Balistica Aço 3,1 15

The piece of plugin code for tabs is:

```js
data: function() {
                var bootstrapTab_d = new Date();
                var bootstrapTab_id = bootstrapTab_d.getTime();
                var bootstrapTab_item = bootstrapTab_contents = '';
                for (var bootstrapTab_i = 0; bootstrapTab_i <= this.data.bootstrapTab_total; bootstrapTab_i++) {
                    eval("bootstrapTab_title = this.data.bootstrapTab_item" + bootstrapTab_i);
                    bootstrapTab_title = bootstrapTab_title != undefined ? bootstrapTab_title : '';
                    eval("bootstrapTab_content = this.data.bootstrapTab_content" + bootstrapTab_i);
                    bootstrapTab_content = bootstrapTab_content != undefined ? bootstrapTab_content : '';
                    eval("bootstrapTab_itemClass = this.data.bootstrapTab_itemClass" + bootstrapTab_i);
                    bootstrapTab_itemClass = bootstrapTab_itemClass != undefined ? bootstrapTab_itemClass : '';
                    eval("bootstrapTab_contentClass = this.data.bootstrapTab_contentClass" + bootstrapTab_i);
                    bootstrapTab_contentClass = bootstrapTab_contentClass != undefined ? bootstrapTab_contentClass : '';
                    if (bootstrapTab_title) {
                        bootstrapTab_item += '<li role="presentation" class="' + bootstrapTab_itemClass + '"><a href="#tab' + bootstrapTab_id + '_' + (bootstrapTab_i + 1) + '" aria-controls="tab' + bootstrapTab_id + '_' + (bootstrapTab_i + 1) + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + bootstrapTab_title + '</a></li>';
                        bootstrapTab_contents += '<div role="tabpanel" class="' + bootstrapTab_contentClass + '" id="tab' + bootstrapTab_id + '_' + (bootstrapTab_i + 1) + '">' + bootstrapTab_content + '</div>'
                    }
                }
                this.element.setAttribute('id', 'collapse' + bootstrapTab_id);
                this.element.$.innerHTML = '<div role="tabpanel"><ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">' + bootstrapTab_item + '</ul><div class="tab-content">' + bootstrapTab_contents + '</div></div>'
   }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you use the double-quotes on the outside, you can use the single quotes on the inside without having to escape them. Either way, you can escape manually with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor the code, and not use eval!

eval is evil http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

instead of

```
eval("bootstrapTab_title = this.data.bootstrapTab_item" + bootstrapTab_i);
```

use `bootstrapTab_item` as an array and do this

```
bootstrapTab_title = this.data.bootstrapTab_item[bootstrapTab_i]
```

really don't know if the error is there, but I think the path to find the error is refactor to eliminate those eval, that could be the source of your problem.